# I deployed my backend on render and it's working fine but after some times my uploded imges deleted but not static images which is present in code

Tags: node.js, server-side-rendering, react-fullstack

I have deployed a nodejs server on render  as free services.  I have an API in my project to upload an image. After upload it appears on my application or on my interface for sometime.

After 5 to 10 minutes images will delete automatically from the server but static images remain in the folder but uploded from deployed application's images deleted automatically. So, I want to ask why this happen? Because of free deployment or any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on where you’re uploading them to in your service.

As you’re using a free plan, you may be uploading them into the service, but then they are lost when the service is redeployed/restarted as there is no persistence by default.

To be uploading them to your Render service and keeping them, you’d need to have a Disk attached (https://render.com/docs/disks) and you’d need to be using a paid plan as disks aren’t available on the free plan. You’ll need to make sure you configure your application to store uploads in the mounted disk path.

The alternative is save your images in external cloud service as Cloudinary

Answer (score 0):

I alredy have that issue, static files not get deleted, but the uploded images does, Then I deployed my application azure free tier, It worked, I guess render free must have to done something with it., Try azure or aws to host your app